# Apache, mod_ssl and "No recognized SSL/TLS toolkit detected"

Tags: apache, ssl, https

I have open ssl installed downloaded from github. Apache 2.X has a problem compiling, any suggestions.

Output of Apache build script:

```
checking whether to enable mod_ssl... checking dependencies
checking for SSL/TLS toolkit base... none
checking for OpenSSL version... checking openssl/opensslv.h usability... no
checking openssl/opensslv.h presence... no
checking for openssl/opensslv.h... no
checking openssl/ssl.h usability... no
checking openssl/ssl.h presence... no
checking for openssl/ssl.h... no
no OpenSSL headers found
checking for SSL-C version... checking sslc.h usability... no
checking sslc.h presence... no
checking for sslc.h... no
no SSL-C headers found
configure: error: ...<br>No recognized SSL/TLS toolkit detected
```

Comment: Where, exactly, is your version of OpenSSL installed?

Answer (score 3):

You have install the openssl libssl-dev packages:

> apt-get install openssl libssl-dev

Comment: centos: `yum install openssl openssl-devel`

Answer (score 0):

> I have open ssl installed downloaded from github. Apache 2.X has a problem compiling, any suggestions.

```
$ ./configure --help | grep -i ssl
  --enable-ssl            SSL/TLS support (mod_ssl)
  --enable-ssl-staticlib-deps
                          link mod_ssl with dependencies of OpenSSL's static
                          Must be specified in addition to --enable-ssl.
  --with-sslport=SSLPORT  Port on which to securelisten (default is 443)
  --with-ssl=PATH         OpenSSL installation directory
```

So, it looks like you need:

```
./configure --enable-ssl --enable-ssl-staticlib-deps --with-ssl=<path to your OpenSSL>
```

I would probably `--enable-ssl-staticlib-deps`. It will keep you out of hot water with loading the wrong `libssl` and `libcrypto` shared objects (namely, the ones in `/usr/lib`). You can omit it, but you need to know how to modify `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Done that. It is complaining that I don't have right SSL/TLS Kit where I have latest compiled and installed in /usr/local/ssl. Packages were downloaded from openssl.org. Openssl in bin is working fine issuing certificate and so on .. not sure what apache build script is looking for yet ..

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the openssl package using following.
$sudo /usr/bin/yum install openssl*

This will install additional pkgs shown below.
 openssl-devel
 openssl-perl
 openssl-static
This resolved the issue for me. Good Luck